# How to update relation when changing foreign key Id

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4

I'm currently developping a wpf + EF application.
I'm facing the following problem.

In one of my entities, I have a property called `StatusId (int)`, and another one called `StatusType`, which is the entity reference towards another entity.

In my code I'm changing the value of the `StatusId`, but the related entity is not sending any notify message. However, the value is correctly changed.

I tried to write some code in the partial class of my entity, which worked.

```
partial void OnStatusIdChanged()
{
   this.OnPropertyChanged("TaskStatusType");
}
```

My question is : Is this the correct way to do this ?

Comment: you might raise, when a property changes, not one but TWO PropertyChanged. When StatusId changes, raise a change on "StatusId" AND StatusType.

Comment: I tought about it, but this is auto-generated code, and I don't want to re-write this code each time I refresh my model.